# Is there a way to get current user's name of a read-only excel file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried using the excel file property `UserStatus[0][0]` but it returned me a `com_error` with a message saying it cannot access to a readonly file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you are opened excel file then you tried to get user status? or else

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. The excel file is open by another PC in the network.
I want to get the current users' names of the file, either it's opened on my PC or another one.

Comment: Just to update: I found a solution: we have to use `WriteReservedBy` instead of `UserStatus[0][0]`

Comment: ok good. Thank you for your updates Lannheday